# Help with Select Query in ado.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, select

I have got a table(newsImages) with columns newsID(Foreign Key) , newsImage , imageID(primary Key), What my query is `Select newsImage From newsImages Where newsID = 'something'`

The query returns all the images with specific newsID, What I want is to remove a row who has image named"something" from the resultant query. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: i dont want to delete it from database, i want to remove it from displaying in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do

```
DELETE FROM newsImage
WHERE newsID = 'something'
```

But be careful, it looks as though your ID field is a text field.

Are you sure that the ID field is guaranteed to be unique? Is it defined as a Primary Key? If not you may have several rows with the same ID and you may delete more than you were expecting to.

**EDIT**

Ah, ok

```
SELECT newsImage From newsImages 
Where newsID = 'something'
AND newsName <> 'somethingElse'
```

Comment: i dont want to delete it from database, i want to remove it from displaying in the results

Comment: <> , what does dat stands for

Comment: <> means not equal to. (the opposite of =) so this query will **not** return any rows where newsName equals 'somethingElse'

Answer (score 1):

To select everything but the newsImage with id 'something'

```
 Select newsImage From newsImages Where newsID <> 'something'
```

to delete newsImage with ID 'something' from the table newsImages

```
 delete from newsImages where newsID = 'something'
```

Comment: i dont want to delete it from database, i want to remove it from displaying in the results

Comment: @Muhammad Awais - I thought that might be the case that's why i wrote the first query which selects everything except the newsImage with ID 'something'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM newsImages WHERE newsImage <> "something" AND newsID = <value>;
```

Comment: i dont want to delete it from database, i want to remove it from displaying in the results

Comment: Are you removing rows based on the results?